# Can you run two toilets on the same horizontal soil/waste pipe?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain

I have a bathroom and toilet next door to eachother. Can I add a toilet in the bathroom using the soil pipe from the toilet next door?

Current layout:

[image]

Proposed layout:

[image]

The existing soil pipe runs horizontally like so:

[image]

Could I change the L bend in the back of the toilet to a T junction and send the pipe through the wall to feed a second toilet?  Given they'd be on the same horizontal soil pipe I worry that flushing one would suck the water out of the other's water trap.

I'm not worried about having two toilets next door to eachother.  I'm considering the most pragmatic approach.

**EDIT:**

To add more context there is another connector below the vertical Tee (not sure what it's called) which waste water from the bath and sink next door runs through so dropping the Tee will require some rework of the bath/sink drainage:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Apologies for my rubbish mspaint drawings - the toilets are not back to back, the existing one faces south in the images.  The new one would also face south (towards the doors).

Comment: Back-to-back (Tee or Cross as you propose) can be a problem. Multiple on a single pipe is fine with correct venting. Where in the world? What plumbing code applies here?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm in the UK (Wales)

Comment: Under IPC rules (probably not the applicable code, but perhaps informative) you can't do back to back water closets unless you have 18" (450mm) between the water closet and the Tee. Obviously not the case as proposed.

Comment: Is there a practical issue to dropping that P-trap down through the floor right where the pan is, then teeing the other to it, also under-floor. That way the whole lot could become invisible. Based on the floorboard orientation, you're not going to hit joists.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've updated the question and included another picture.  Essentailly there's another connector for bath / sink waste.  Moving the Tee down looks very daunting.

Comment: Let's assume you're only going to be doing this once & that the floors are going to have to come up anyway ;) Drop the P trap below the floor, lose the 3" junction & lower the 4" to there. Drop the new pan to the same level & run the other outlets to that first. You can either have two hideously ugly drains visible in two bathrooms… or none. Investigate whether you can get a shorter junction with valve to get it all below the floor [I'm not great on what's available, my dad was the plumber, not me;) but I have a valve on my stack that's only about 3" high.

Comment: Note the question is about "on the same horizontal pipe", but the actual situation is "back to back" as addressed in some comments.  It's not just flow from two toilets into one horizontal, it's flow from the new toilet flowing past the old toilet's trap from a higher level.  The new toilet will actually deposit waste into the old toilet's trap.  If you drop them BOTH below the floor as suggested. then you can ask your more vanilla question about sharing a horizontal.

Comment: @jay613 apologies for my rubbish mspaint drawings.  The toilets are not back to back, they face south in the image.

Comment: 'back to back' in this instance refers to the two being on the same pipe run, not their geographical orientation. In graphic terms, if you flush one, you don't want poo appearing in the other, or in the shower, or inversely, one sucking the other dry. You need to split the levels, or possibly use a Y-structure & AAV valves on each unit, toilets, shower, sink. It would be good to know if any of your walls are to the exterior - as that might be your get out of jail free card - do the whole thing outdoors.

Comment: "Back to back" has specific meaning especially in high rise buildings, and I was wrong to use the term exactly. But was just trying to amplify what the other comments were suggesting as @Tetsujin explains.  That is, your question stands if the horizontal waste pipe is *below* all the trap exits, so waste would have to flow upwards to enter other fixtures.  Then the concern is the fitness of the pipe to carry the waste, and the venting.  But in your design the new toilet WILL dump poop into the old one's trap.  And yes, In a real back-to-back scenario, not yours, that can happen forcefully!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  The north wall is indeed an exterior wall so running it all outside sounds like the best option.  Can also drop the P under the floor as well.  I will go away and meditate on it.